# If the spectral radius of a matrix is less than 1, then the matrix has a norm which is less than 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an arbitrary square matrix and define $ \rho(A)$ to be the maximal eigenvalue of $A$ in absolute value. If $ \rho(A)<1,$  then there exists a norm of $A$ such that $ \| A \|<1.$ How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the [following result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127346/spectral-radius-and-a-curious-equality/127352#127352): $\rho(A)=\inf\{\lVert A\rVert,\lVert\cdot\rVert\mbox{ matrix norm}\}$ and apply the definition of $\inf$ to $\varepsilon:=\frac{1-\rho(A)}2$.

Comment: Hi! Late question, but is there a matrix norm which will always satisfy this. I know $||.||_2$ norm doesn't need to be less than 1 if $\rho(A) < 1$. Bu what about $||.||_3$? Or $||.||_n$.

Comment: late answer, but i am pretty sure this theorem only guarantees the existence of some matrix norm satisfying the condition ||A|| < 1, but you won't be able to know which norm it is

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is symmetric then the Euclidean norm of $A$ is $\rho(A)$. If it is not symmetric, define the block matrix $$ B=\begin{array} 0 0  & A \\  A^t & 0  \end{array} \ . $$  Then the norm of $A$ is equal to norm of $B$ and you may define the norm of $A$ that way.